# NameError: name 'User' is not defined (when flask shell)

Tags: python, flask

This is my *microblog.py* file, environment, centos7.

```
from app import app,db
from app.models import User,Post
@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
return {'db':db,'User':User,'Post':Post}
```

when I input `flask shell`, and want to add `User`:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr 10 2018, 17:08:37) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux
App: app [production]
Instance: /root/code/microblog/instance
>>> User
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'User' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Is this based on Miguel Greenberg's tutorial?

Comment: See *The "flask shell" Command* section from this blog.

Comment: @SantoshKumar Miss the link?

Comment: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/migrating-from-flask-script-to-the-new-flask-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens if you run `flask shell` (or `venv/bin/flask shell`) without first setting `FLASK_APP=microblog.py`.

```
FLASK_APP=microblog.py flask shell
```

Should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import User from app.models. To do this, in terminal type:

```
>>> from app.models import User
>>> User
```

Then, user should be defined. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: thank you for your answer .but I think flask shell has include "from app.models import User".